# Resource.Id not working in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

This is main.axml file.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myListView" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

And this is the MainActivity.cs file :

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

```
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    Glop = new List<string>();

    Glop.Add("Tom");
    Glop.Add("Dick");
    Glop.Add("Harry");

    Name = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);

}
```

I am trying to create a Listview in Xamarin Android.

I have changed the android Id to myListView and also have tried to rebuild the app but it still shows as an error . What should I do now ?

Comment: Clean and Rebuild your project. It should then regenerate the `Resources.designer.cs` file which should include your new `Id` definition.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try rebuilding the app again and saving the main.axml file .

- Build > Clean Solution
- Build Solution

Comment: I have the same problem and this solution isn't working for me. The only way to get rid of the error is to Rebuild and Restart Visual Studio 2017. Clean is not necessary. Is this a bug? Intellisense is not updating correctly or something?

Answer (score 21):

Adjust properties for resource file like here:

[image]

Comment: After doing this, the id was recognized and I didn't need to clean/rebuild after editing the id value.

Comment: Agreed.  This was the fix fo rme.

Comment: In my case IntelliSense was giving errors and i couldn't find my components by id, and they were not listed, although the app was being built successfully and even running. This solution worked for me and now the components are listed. Thank you so much.

Comment: This worked for me after I found one of my layouts had been setup as an XML file instead of an AXML file, plus I had renamed the layout in the process. The Build Action was Content and the Custom Tool was blank, causing a "ghost" error that didn't show in the Error List window but showed in the Output window details.  Setting the options as shown above fixed up the error.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This was the only remedy that resolved my issue.

Comment: These properties were set before in my project and the problem is the same

Answer (score 12):

**For Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview (V 16.0.0, Pr 5.0):**

For this problem and a lot of the problem with the designer I have to repeatedly do the following:

- Save all documents and close VS.
- Navigate to the project folder in your file browser
- Delete (or rename, if you're paranoid) the "obj" and "bin" folders
- Relaunch VS and try the designer again.

With this version (granted, it's still beta) running a clean on the project with the designer open will cause access permission errors that can be corrected with these steps.

Answer (score 3):

1)Build -> Clean Solution

2)Build Solution

Answer (score 2):

Option 1) Make sure update the Xamarin.Android (Tools>Options>Xamarin>Other>Check Now)

Option 2) Run VS as Administrator and Build>Clean and Rebuild the solution.

For my case option 1 did work. [image]

Comment: Why do you need to run VS as administrator ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this kind of problem. The cause may be from the duplicate resource IDs in the project. For instance, this problem occurs when you copy a layout file (.axml) and simply paste directly into the layout resource folder in the solution explorer pane without meticulous resource ID name review in it.

Since the ID reference rule in the project's namespace is to be unique. While the resource ID is auto-generating in the .Designer file, The VS couldn't determine which one is the right one you intend to use, so all cases of the same resource IDs may be skipped and unprocessed without warning.

The result is - after I made a duplicate layout file in the same project, later I couldn't reference resource name or ID of them while I'm coding.

The solution for me is to look for the duplicate IDs name in the project and correct them to be unique.