# xamarin id's not being found with findviewbyid

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

when I reference my Xamarin id in my C# code it says ID does not exist.

tried rebuilding cleaning and building many times. also tried changing the ID's and rebuilding. restarting VS many times.

Xamarin

```
          <Button
                    android:text="Log in"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/slc_style"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:id="@+id/btnLILogIn1" />

 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
                FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLILogIn1);
    }[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Hi,which verion nubmer of vs2019. Having a try with cleaning project, then rebuilding it.If not working , closes project and reopen it to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually delete the bin and obj directories inside your project folder. This resolved this issue for me. Otherwise the Resource.designer.cs file doesn't get properly updated.

Comment: every time I change the id I need to delete that bin and obj folders again. any way to make visual studio work properly to update it when I build?

Comment: are you using VS2019? It just could be a bug within Visual Studio itself. I tested with VS2019. In an ideal world it should happen during build time, but even running Visual Studio in administrator mode didn't fix it.

Comment: the issue has been existing for a long time. Unfortunately there is no other way. Same issue has been raised here over three years ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303051/resource-id-not-working-in-xamarin

If my answer was helpful then please mark it as accepted answer :)